# template tags in Flask? Possible?

Tags: python, templates, flask, django-templates

When I tried Django I really liked template tags there. I read through the Flask documentation quickly and maybe missed something, but it seems that such a thing which works in some kind of similar way is not implemented in Flask? If not, maybe there is some extension or maybe somehow going deeply to API this could be implemented?

If not... then how you guys load the content in the template which is common for example for all the pages? Like I want to have block showing latest blog entries all around my website.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read Flask documentation? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#

Comment: So you suggest to use context processors or this g object?

Comment: @IgnasB. Yes, context processors is the Flask way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask's alternative to Django template tags is [Context Processors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#context-processors).

Comment: But is there something like inclusion_tag from django, so that I can include sub-template with specific context that is separate from main template?

Comment: Something like `{% include "sidebar.html" without context %}` ?

Comment: `include without context` will not let me pass custom context based on parameters. I guess what I was looking for is `macro` (+ context processor in some cases). `include without context` + `context processor` could be used if sub-template needs no parametrisation.

Comment: to somewhat sum it up: according to docs it seems that Django `inclusion_tag` (ability to render sub-template with custom parametrised context) can be simulated in Flask using following few ways: option a) `macro` + `context processor` (context processor used if additional custom context is needed), option b) use `{% with %}{% set ... ` statement to temporary rename local context variable to the name used by sub-template, followed by inclusion of sub-template `{% include ... %}`